# Animation pull down and comes back

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, android-animation

Hy, i am trying to implement this animation. Could anybody help me?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XfmKq-ihN0&feature=youtu.be

I've tryed using pull to refresh library but the results are not quite as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add effect bounce to ScrollView in android

**Step 1**: Create new file BounceScrollView in package com.base.view

public class BouncyScroll extends ScrollView {
    private ScrollCallbacks mCallbacks;

```
private static final int MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 200;

private Context mContext;
private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;

public BouncyScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mContext = context;
    initBounceScrollView();
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
    return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
}

public void setCallbacks(ScrollCallbacks listener) {
    mCallbacks = listener;
}

private void initBounceScrollView() {
    // get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max
    // overscroll distance
    // variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen
    // size

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    final float density = metrics.density;

    mMaxYOverscrollDistance = (int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE);

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
}

static interface ScrollCallbacks {
    public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
        int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
        int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
    // This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming
    // maxOverScrollY with our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance;
    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY,
            scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX,
            mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);
}
```

}
**Step 2:** At your layout, please change

```
<ScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

to

```
<com.base.view.BounceScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but i'm still having some problems related to overScrollBy method. It seems is not defined in ScrollView. Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: This worked for me....

Did you chnged your scrollvie to your class?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly how you said. What target API are you using?

Comment: It was the api. Thank's it's working